# Why is my CSS file not linking to my HTML file on VS Code?

Tags: html, css, file, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

I'm working on VS code, and I'm having difficulty linking my style sheet to my index.html file. When I look at the folder that my files are in, my css file saves as a web page-- is that typical? I'm wondering if that is my problem...

The code that I am using to link my css file to my html file is:

link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="stylesheets.css"

The above code is wrapped in <>...but when I put it into the question, the code ends up not showing up, so that's why does are missing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ensure the name you passed into the href attribute is the same with the name you used in saving your style sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the **rel** you should use ***stylesheet*** instead of ***stylesheets***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets.css">
```

and make sure stylesheets file and HTML file in the folder

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!